# Multiple uploads to multiple folders - PHP

Tags: php, file-upload, upload

I am attempting to upload multiple files into multiple folders. Unfortunately, with little success.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

I have two form fields:

```
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="<?php echo $max; ?>" />
<input name="menu" type="file" class="input_event noBorder" title="Upload Menu" />


<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="<?php echo $max; ?>" />
<input name="img" type="file" class="input_event noBorder" title="Upload Img" />
```

I would like to use one for uploading images, and the other to upload pdf's and/or word docs.
I would also like for these two files to be saved into their corresponding folders (/imgs and /docs).

**Some things i have tried**

- have tried to have two of these, each pointing to the correct path
- have tried multiple classes to handle each file
- have added array brackets to the input name field (ex: `name="menu[]"`)

I imagine i need to change somethings in the class itself; however i am learning php and this class is cobbled together from 3 books, dozens of Google searches, and a few posts i found here on stack.

Exactly what i need to change is still far beyond me.

**Relevant portion of on-page PHP code:**

```
$max = 400000;
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { //MAIN IF STATEMENT  

$destination = './uploads/menus_up/';
try {
$upload = new Upload_File($destination);
$upload->move();
$result = $upload->getMessages();
} catch (Exception $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

**Upload class:**

```
class Upload_File {

    protected $_uploaded = array();
    protected $_destination;
    protected $_max = 400000;
    protected $_messages = array();
    protected $_permitted = array('image/gif',
                                'image/jpeg',
                                'image/pjpeg',
                                'image/png');
    protected $_renamed = false;

    public function __construct($path) {
    if (!is_dir($path) || !is_writable($path)) {
        throw new Exception("$path must be a valid, writable directory.");
    }
    $this->_destination = $path;
    $this->_uploaded = $_FILES;
    }

    public function getMaxSize() {
    return number_format($this->_max/1024, 1) . 'kB';
    }

    public function setMaxSize($num) {
    if (!is_numeric($num)) {
        throw new Exception("Maximum size must be a number.");
    }
    $this->_max = (int) $num;
    }

    public function move($overwrite = false) {
    $field = current($this->_uploaded);
    if (is_array($field['name'])) {
        foreach ($field['name'] as $number => $filename) {
        // process multiple upload
        $this->_renamed = false;
        $this->processFile($filename, $field['error'][$number], $field['size'][$number], $field['type'][$number], $field['tmp_name'][$number], $overwrite); 
        }
    } else {
        $this->processFile($field['name'], $field['error'], $field['size'], $field['type'], $field['tmp_name'], $overwrite);
    }
    }

    public function getMessages() {
    return $this->_messages;
    }

    protected function checkError($filename, $error) {
    switch ($error) {
        case 0:
        return true;
        case 1:
        case 2:
            $this->_messages[] = "$filename exceeds maximum size: " . $this->getMaxSize();
        return true;
        case 3:
        $this->_messages[] = "Error uploading $filename. Please try again.";
        return false;
        case 4:
        $this->_messages[] = 'No file selected.';
        return false;
        default:
        $this->_messages[] = "System error uploading $filename. Contact webmaster.";
        return false;
    }
    }

    protected function checkSize($filename, $size) {
    if ($size == 0) {
        return false;
    } elseif ($size > $this->_max) {
        $this->_messages[] = "$filename exceeds maximum size: " . $this->getMaxSize();
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
    }

    protected function checkType($filename, $type) {
    if (empty($type)) {
        return false;
    } elseif (!in_array($type, $this->_permitted)) {
        $this->_messages[] = "$filename is not a permitted type of file.";
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
    }

    public function addPermittedTypes($types) {
    $types = (array) $types;
        $this->isValidMime($types);
    $this->_permitted = array_merge($this->_permitted, $types);
    }

    protected function isValidMime($types) {
        $alsoValid = array('image/tiff',
                             'application/pdf',
                             'application/msword');
        $valid = array_merge($this->_permitted, $alsoValid);
    foreach ($types as $type) {
        if (!in_array($type, $valid)) {
        throw new Exception("$type is not a permitted MIME type");
        }
    }
    }

    protected function checkName($name, $overwrite) {
    $nospaces = str_replace(' ', '_', $name);
    if ($nospaces != $name) {
        $this->_renamed = true;
    }
    if (!$overwrite) {
        $existing = scandir($this->_destination);
        if (in_array($nospaces, $existing)) {
        $dot = strrpos($nospaces, '.');
        if ($dot) {
            $base = substr($nospaces, 0, $dot);
            $extension = substr($nospaces, $dot);
        } else {
            $base = $nospaces;
            $extension = '';
        }
        $i = 1;
        do {
            $nospaces = $base . '_' . $i++ . $extension;
        } while (in_array($nospaces, $existing));
        $this->_renamed = true;
        }
    }
    return $nospaces;
    }

    protected function processFile($filename, $error, $size, $type, $tmp_name, $overwrite) {
    $OK = $this->checkError($filename, $error);
    if ($OK) {
        $sizeOK = $this->checkSize($filename, $size);
        $typeOK = $this->checkType($filename, $type);
        if ($sizeOK && $typeOK) {
        $name = $this->checkName($filename, $overwrite);
        $success = move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $this->_destination . $name);
        if ($success) {
            $message = "$filename uploaded successfully";
            if ($this->_renamed) {
                $message .= " and renamed $name";
            }
            $this->_messages[] = $message;
        } else {
            $this->_messages[] = "Could not upload $filename";
        }
        }
    }
    }

}//END CLASS....Upload_Menu
```

**Striped down class**

```
    protected $_uploaded = array();
    protected $_destination;
    protected $_max = 400000;
    protected $_messages = array();
    protected $_permitted = array('image/gif',
                                'image/jpeg',
                                'image/pjpeg',
                                'image/png');
    protected $_renamed = false;

    public function __construct($path) {
    if (!is_dir($path) || !is_writable($path)) {
        throw new Exception("$path must be a valid, writable directory.");
    }
    $this->_destination = $path;
    $this->_uploaded = $_FILES;
    }

    public function move() {
    $field = current($this->_uploaded);
    $success = move_uploaded_file($field['tmp_name'], $this->_destination . $field['name']);
    if ($success) {
        $this->_messages[] = $field['name'] . ' uploaded successfully';
    } else {
        $this->_messages[] = 'Could not upload ' . $field['name'];
    }
    }

    public function getMessages() {
    return $this->_messages;
    }
```

Comment: That's a lot of code to upload a file. You should try to narrow down the problem.

Comment: yea its a bit excessive; but i was tinkering and then figured i would create a class that did everything all at once... the error handling, file renaming, overwrite protection, etc. Admittedly, i got a bit carried away. However, now that i spent so much time on this thing, I want to finish it completely. Unfortunately have hit a roadblock. lol

Comment: That's no problem, just get the basics working and add features (or method calls) as you get each step working. For now you should get rid of most of it (at least here) and post a bare example of where it goes wrong. And what goes wrong exactly.

Comment: This actually works for what i initially wanted, it's just not doing what i want it to do now. It will upload single or multiple files; however it will only do so from a single input field and only to one folder. I have tried to work with a striped down version but still cant figure out how to make the class process two files and save them into separate folders.

Comment: Added the striped down version of the class to the bottom of my post, maybe you can see a way of modifying that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

So...for anyone who may come across this in the future, here is a less than elegant, but ultimately effective solution.

```
pathinfo($string, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)  FTW!
```

I add a sorting mechanism to my `processFile` method and Wallah!

```
protected function processFile($filename, $error, $size, $type, $tmp_name, $overwrite) {
$OK = $this->checkError($filename, $error);
if ($OK) {
  $sizeOK = $this->checkSize($filename, $size);
  $typeOK = $this->checkType($filename, $type);
  if ($sizeOK && $typeOK) {
    $name = $this->checkName($filename, $overwrite);

    /************************ADDED HERE************************************/
    if (pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == 'pdf' || 'doc' || 'docx'){
        $this->_destination = './uploads/menus_up/';
    if (pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == 'png' || 'jpeg' || 'gif'){
        $this->_destination = './uploads/eventBG_up/';  
    /**********************************************************************/

    $success = move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $this->_destination . $name);
    if ($success) {
        $message = "$filename uploaded successfully";
        if ($this->_renamed) {
          $message .= " and renamed $name";
        }
        $this->_messages[] = $message;
    } else {
      $this->_messages[] = "Could not upload $filename";
     }
   }
  }
 }  
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would take a slightly different approach: Send a specific file to the constructor when you create your object like:

```
$upload = new Upload_File($_FILES['menu'], $destination);
```

Then you have all the information you need in your class and you don't have to access global variables from within your class.

You can then loop over your `$_FILES` array to add every file or put that in a different class.

It would require some rewriting in the class but it would make it more flexible and it would meet your needs.

Comment: This would require that i set two instances in order to process both files, right? For example:    $upload = new Upload_File($_FILES['menu'], $destination); and    $upload = new Upload_File($_FILES['img'], $destination);